# Is it possible to get the timestamp from an existing picture in android studio?

Tags: android

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve the time of an existing picture? So i basically want to use the time when the picture was taken?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ExifInterface` with the image. You can then grab any attribute that is available, including the timestamp of when the image was taken. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html)

```
String timestamp = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

Comment: Thanks i will check later today!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `ExifInterface` , it provides information about image like orientation , date and time of creation if it's available

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pathToTheImage);
String datetime =  exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

for more attribute have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

Comment: Thanks i will check later today!